# Github Repository Stopping at 50%

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I am using GitGui to clone a repository through Beanstalk app (I know, I should be using the CLI, but for now I am needing to use the GitGui). I am on Windows 7 (32bit), and I am also noticing that I am being prompted for the log in credentials a few times in the process.

The issue is that the cloning process either stalls at 50% or does not complete at all. Perhaps I don't know how to ascertain that it is complete, or if there is something that I need to know about the cloning process via GUI. I understand that there may be some instances where only a CLI clone will work.

Please forgive any ignorance or vagueness in the question, I'm new to the Git process and still trying to sort my way through the modern dev environment of git, grunt, and all of the other tools and versioning.

Thanks so much for any insight and pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the git client tools instead to do a clone with:

```
git clone http://repo
```

and see if that works first. There may be other network problems that are causing the failure, and you should reduce the problem to the smallest possible reproducible case before others can help further.